# Re drawing a view on orientation change

Tags: android, viewgroup, android-view, android-orientation

I am using a`TextView` in a `ViewGroup` and I am using that `ViewGroup` to create a gallery like scrollable UI. The `TextView` has its entire background filled with a single color. All is working fine except that when I change my `orientation` from `portrait` to `landscape` to `portrait` and vice-versa, the `TextView's` original size is maintained and hence, the drawing looks disoriented. But as soon as I pan or scroll, it is re-corrected. My class which extends `ViewGroup` does not take care of the drawing part and I have tried the following :

- Invalidating the `ViewGroup`.
- Invalidating the current view on display.
- Implementing `onConfigurationChanged` (with appropriate changes in Manifest).

I don't want to go though the process of re-creating the `TextView` after saving the currentState  when the configuration is changed. Here's my code snippet of adding the views in the `ViewGroup` :-

```
final int[] backgroundColors = { Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(i + 1));
        textView.setTextSize(100);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColors[i]);
        mWorkspace.addView(textView);
    }
    //mWorkspace.setSeparator(R.drawable.seperator);
    setContentView(mWorkspace);
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have a similar issue - I display a battery graphic in portrait mode, "cut" it using `setBounds()` but when I switch to landscape and back to portrait, the original "full" battery is shown. The previous value is not remembered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the textview to mWorkspace after the call to setContentView instead of before.

Until that point it may not be possible to determine the screen orientation and hence calculate the scaling properly.

Moving the textbox add down to onStart or onResume will also have an effect, though I have found that the scaling works best from onCreate.

Comment: This part is coded in my onCreate() and is working fine. I'm having problems only during the orientation change.

Comment: onCreate is executed after a rotate so technically it is only working fine where the orientation is the same as when the application started. Setting the ContentView before adding the textviews to it will cause onMeasure to be called and allow for proper scaling when they are added. (Subsequent Panning and scrolling would have used the new, now correct, measurement values and so appeared to sort out the scaling.)